# How to specify number of subdivide sections in Blender 2.8x?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

So I know about subdividing, and was subdividing a face for a rounded TV screen. However, it only allows me to subdivide a 2^x number of faces and only allows the same number of per side (4x4, 8x8, 16x16 etc.)
Is there a way to subdivide so I could have a non-square number of new faces? Thanks in advance and sorry for a newbie question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure thing.

- Subdivision always splits 1 face into 4. No way around it.
- But you can make uneven subdivision manually using *Loop Cuts*.

[image]